# Whether kafka broker holds replication set instead of partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka

From the Kafka documentation and from some other blogs I read, I concluded that one kafka-broker consists of one partition of topics. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252307/kafka-broker-vs-topic) It says one Kafka-broker holds only one partition. I have only one broker in my system, But I can able to create a topic with 3 partitions and 1 replication factor. I also tried to create a topic with 3 partitions and 3 replication factor with only one broker. It throws below error

`Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
[2017-10-21 15:35:25,928] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)`.

So I have a query.

1. Whether Kafka-broker holds replication instead of a partition?
2. If I create 3 partitions with a single broker, what happens?
3. In such case of 1 broker, 1 replica and 3 partition , how many partitions of single topic can kafka-broker hold?

Somebody, please explain what happens here.

Answer (score 5):

The post you are reffering to doesn't say that one broker can store only one partitions. It just says that partition is not splittable between brokers (topic is). Actually I manage a brokers with thousands of partitions. So, for your questions:

1. Kafka brokers hold many partitions. Replication is the way to store multiple copies of partitions across cluster.
2. If you create topic with 3 partitions on single node cluster, the broker will hold the data for all the partitions. Replication is not possible since it requires more nodes.
3. All of them.

Comment: So replication referred here is the replication of broker, not topic.

Comment: No, you set replication on topics. But this is limited by number of brokers in the cluster.

Comment: So what happens if I have 4 partitions, 2 replicas and 2 brokers. What about the replication here.

Comment: Both brokers will hold these 4 partitions as you request to hold 2 copies of partition data across cluster.

Comment: Thank You. Finally, One question, If I have two topics, each topic have 4 partitions and replica for the first topic is one and second one is 2. I have two Kafka-broker, in such case what will happen.

Comment: On balanced cluster each broker will hold data for 6 partitions (2 from topic1 and 4 from topic2).

Answer (score 1):

Summary: The replication factor has to be equal or less in number compared to the number of brokers you have.